# Sidekick browser unable to catch *.json file in Linux

Tags: browser, kerberos

**Kerberos** authentication working well for me in Chrome, Edge, Brave, Vivaldi and Firefox. However, Sidekick browser is unable to read the **.json** file I created in `/etc/opt/sidekick/policies/managed/policies.json`

I am looking for a solution to enable the Kerberos authentication in Sidekick browser.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: {
        "AuthServerAllowlist": "*.example.com"
}

Answer (score 0):

On Twitter, Sidekick replied to try

> /etc/sidekick/policies/managed/policies.json

However, I am yet to try.